# How can I create a Java web application which looks the same as my desktop?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I want create a web application which looks similar as my Windows 7 desktop. I am using JSP and JSF. I wonder how I could create a start button and gadgets. Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

[PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) has a [Mac OS X dock demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/macosx.jsf). The main components are:

- Top menu bar: [`<p:menubar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf)
- Dialog: [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf)
- Dock: [`<p:dock>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dock.jsf)
- Mac OS X theme: with help of [jQuery ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

(see also *View > Source* in top menu bar of the demo page)

---

That said, I would strongly recommend to drop JSP altogether and go ahead with Facelets (XHTML) for JSF. However, your question history hints here and there that you're already using Facelets. Why would you fall back to vintage JSP then?

Comment: This is for Mac, what about Windows?

Comment: @Odelya: It's a matter of a different theme :) The [Redmond](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf?theme=redmond) theme comes close.

Comment: Hi BalusC i wonder use jsp:include and ui:include page can you give me suggest ? thank you

Comment: `jsp:include` is for JSP and `ui:include` is for Facelets. JSP is not the same as Facelets. They cannot be used together. They are both view technologies. Facelets is the successor of JSP. Facelets is a better choice.